# divs move when resizing the page

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a timeline on a site I'm trying to recreate and when I resize the window to mobile, the divs get separated. I'm a little far into the site and am very cautious about what I need to do to make this work. The timeline has icons (which have their own div) & a icon background (which have their own div too) but I think I need to wrap them around in one larger div to make this work, but not sure how.

See images here for a before I resize and after I resize:

[image]

See how the icons get separated from the background?

[image]

Html code for each item in timeline:

```
                    <div class="timeline_item">
                     <div class="timeline_time"><p><em>1 hr ago</em></p></div>
                     <div class="icon_background"></div>
                     <div class="timeline_icon "><i class="ss-icon">doc</i></div>
                     <div class="timeline_text"><p>You read the article </p> </div>                  
                    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.timeline_item {
 width: 100%;
 padding-bottom: 17%;
}

.timeline_item .timeline_time {
 float: left;
 width: 20%;
}

.timeline_item .timeline_icon {
 float: left;
 width: 1%;
 }

.timeline_item .timeline_text {
 float: left;
 width: 65%;
 padding-left: 3%;
}

.timeline_icon {
 margin-left: -4%;
 margin-top: 2.5%;
}
```

Comment: A JSfiddle would be of some assistance? Are you using media queries?

Comment: Can you provide a demo link or create a js fiddle?

I don't see the CSS for the icon background...

I would consider positioning the icon, background and time with absolute positioning instead. Give `.timeline_item` some padding on the left equal to width of the time and your icon. Then you give `.timeline_text` `width:100%` and it will expand and contract without distorting the icon and time.

Comment: Are those icons from symbolset.com? We'd need to see the js/css for how those icons are created.

Comment: Position your icon elements inside the circular divs, not separately. I'm not sure if I am right (no way for me to test) but I think your icons are floating like a layer above your circular divs. Make the circular divs `position:relative;` and make the icons `position:absolute;` then position them (the icon class) inside the circular div. You should also use media queries if possible, as mentioned by @Paulie_D I'm sorry if this is confusing, but I am struggling to give you an answer without a codepen, fiddle, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Without access to a proper Jsfiddle Demo, here's one suggestion with a reduced HTML structure which uses pseudo-elements.

You could use an icon-font, sprite or whatever where I have used a single letter.

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/jIGlA)

**HTML**

```
<div class="timeline">

  <article class="timeline_item">
    <div class="timeline_time">
      <p>1 hr ago<p>
    </div>
    <div class="timeline_text" data-event-type="doc"><p>You read the article </p> </div>                  
  </article>

  <article class="timeline_item">
    <div class="timeline_time">
      <p>1 hr ago<p>
    </div>
    <div class="timeline_text" data-event-type="alert"><p>You have a 'Do Not Miss' Meeting scheduled for tomorrow 9a.m.</p> </div>                  
  </article>

  <article class="timeline_item">
    <div class="timeline_time"><p>1 hr ago<p>
    </div>
    <div class="timeline_text" data-event-type="video"><p>You watched a video</p> </div>                  
  </article>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.timeline {
  width:50%;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  border:1px solid lightgrey;
}

.timeline_item {
  display: table;
  width:100%;
}
.timeline_time,
.timeline_text {
  display: table-cell;
  padding:1rem 2rem;
}

.timeline_time {
  width:25%;
  text-align: right;
  border-right:1px solid lightgrey;
}

.timeline_text {
  position: relative;
}
[data-event-type]:before {
  position: absolute;
  content:"";
  width:32px;
  height:32px;
  line-height: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  color:white;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,50%);
}

[data-event-type="doc"]:before {
  content:"D";
  background: #00f;
}

[data-event-type="alert"]:before {
    content:"A";
  background: #f00;
}
[data-event-type="video"]:before {
    content:"V";
  background: #0f0;
}
```

The techniques shown here might help you wit your current issue(s).

**There are, of course, alternatives to this layout method, including floats and actual tables. some of those will require 'fixes' to achieve the 'equal heights' that is native to CSS tables.**

Comment: I up voted this since I like it a lot. I made one too since I needed one for another project, I'm going to use a definition list instead for mine.

Answer (score 0):

Since there was no complete html or css, this is a mobile first approach that requires fairly decent css skills to follow, but it starts off in a logical way for small viewports and adjusts fluidly. The min-width is where the layout for larger view ports starts. The styles before this are global (shared by all view port sizes).

### DEMO: http://jsbin.com/zerijo/1/

http://jsbin.com/zerijo/1/edit

CSS:

```
/*demo only body */
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background:#fff;
    padding:5%;
}

/* ---------- timeline styles ------------ */

.timeline_wrapper:after, .timeline_item:after {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
}

.timeline_wrapper, .timeline_item {
    display: inline-block
}

* html .timeline_wrapper, * html .timeline_item {
    height: 1%
}

.timeline_wrapper, .timeline_item {
    display: block
}

.timeline_wrapper,
.timeline_wrapper div,
.timeline_wrapper *:before,
.timeline_wrapper *:after {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.timeline_wrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 10px;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

.timeline_wrapper:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 15px;
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    border-right: 1px solid #777;
    width: 1px;
    z-index: -1;
}

.timeline_wrapper p {
    margin: 0
}

.timeline_icon i {
    background: red;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 32px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #fff;
    float: left;
}

.timeline_text {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 0 0 40px;
}

.timeline_time {
    padding-left: 40px
}

.timeline_item {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.timeline_item:not(:last-child) {
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}



@media (min-width:480px) { 
    .timeline_wrapper {
        position: relative;
        padding-top: 10px;
    }

    .timeline_wrapper:before {
        left: 27%
    }

    .timeline_item > div {
        float: left;
        position: relative;
    }

    .timeline_time {
        width: 22%;
        text-align: right;
        padding: 0;
        left: -10%;
    }

    .timeline_icon {
        width: 10%;
        min-height: 50px;
        left: 22%;
        top:-5px;
    }

    .timeline_icon i {
        margin: 0 auto;
        float: none;
    }

    .timeline_text {
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: -37%;
        padding: 0 0 0 37%;
    }
}
```

HTML -- structured differently for mobile then adjusted position at the min-width:

```
<div class="timeline_wrapper">
 <div class="timeline_item">
  <div class="timeline_icon">
   <i class="your-icon"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="timeline_time">
   <p><em>1 hr ago</em></p>
  </div>
  <div class="timeline_text">
   <p>Lack of peppering one's sentences with gerunds.Lack of peppering one's sentences with gerunds. Lack of peppering one's sentences with gerunds. You read the article </p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="timeline_item">
  <div class="timeline_icon">
   <i class="your-icon"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="timeline_time">
   <p><em>1 hr ago</em></p>
  </div>
  <div class="timeline_text">
   <p>You read the article Lack of peppering one's sentences with gerunds. Lack of peppering one's sentences with gerunds.Lack of peppering one's sentences with gerunds.Lack of peppering one's sentences with gerunds.</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="timeline_item">
  <div class="timeline_icon">
   <i class="your-icon"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="timeline_time">
   <p><em>1 hr ago</em></p>
  </div>
  <div class="timeline_text">
   <p>You read the article.</p>
  </div>
 </div>
```